# jquery unterminated string literal when loading dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$str is loading dynamic content from admin panel (tinymce) in following format

$str = 'First Line
    Second Line 
   Third Line';

Now when i try to access this variable then it gives me unterminated string literal  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var a = '<?php echo $str;?>';
        $('#abc').html(a);                      
    });    
</script>
<div id="abc"></div>
```

when i convert string to `$str = 'First line Second line Third line';` then it does not give error but my string is in above way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dumping a PHP variable into JavaScript, ALWAYS use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode). Like this:

```
var a = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>;
```

Note no quotes around the PHP code, this is important! PHP will add the quotes for you and escape everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the line breaks, they're not valid inside a JavaScript string literal. If you want multiple lines in a JavaScript string, use a backslash (`\`):

```
var testString = 'This is \
    a test';
```

Even then, multiple whitespace (including linebreaks) will be removed when it's set as the content of an HTML element.

That said, I don't see why you're using the JavaScript to do this at all, you could simply do:

```
<div id="jaspreet"><?php echo $str;?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but content is coming from admin section editor means admin is managing content from admin panel so how can i give slash after each line

Comment: "multiple whitespace will be removed" - unless you're using `white-space:pre-wrap` or similar. Then again, considering how few people even know that exists, they probably aren't.

Comment: admin inserting content in following format

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-5"><img title="Facebook" src="images/fb128.png" alt="Facebook" /></div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="form-group"><label>You&rsquo;ve got mail!</label>
<p>Check your email account and click on the link to continue to activate your MyOffer account</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>